# Ajax form no $_POST data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to get this Ajax form to work and I think i'm mostly there. Essentially, the concept is that a user can click "Add" and it submits the form and appends a new clone (with incrementing ID etc.) to the bottom, repeatable ad infinitum.

So, from what I can tell on my form it is correctly serialising the last form and is running through the query, Chromes network feature implies an array has been sent featuring the correct data to the page I'm wanting to send it to, but "$_POST" is not being set on the PHP end and I can't work out why.

Here is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#form_button").click(function() {
 var formData = $("form:last").serialize();
  console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Academic_Submit.php',
        data: formData,
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   alert("Yay!");
 },
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
    } 

  });
}); 
</script>
```

At the moment, I get "YAY" returned, implying it was success, so I'm not sure the issue is this end, Currently all my PHP file is doing is

```
<?php


 $arr = get_defined_vars();
 var_dump($arr);

 ?>
```

but I have tried print_r($_POST) to no luck. Can anybody shed any light on what could possibly be causing this, as I can't think of what else to try.

Comment: Show us a `console.log()` of `formData`

Comment: Also, what is `#form_button`?  If that is a _submit_ button inside a form, then you need to prevent the default form submit, otherwise the browser will submit the form the normal way.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the responses. So i've actually been able to figure out the issue...and it was, ahem User error on my part and thinking PHP would return something in the HTML...which it obviously wouldn't (without another Ajax request)